# Using (Re)Captcha without any server code?

Tags: server, recaptcha

Is it posible to use the recaptcha API without any server side code? I keep getting a CORS error. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871555/access-control-allow-origin-error-in-recaptcha-call) saying Recaptcha doesn't allow requests directly from browsers.
I also tried creating a php proxy on my server (although defeating the purpose of this question) but keep getting an error that the challenge field is not valid even though I'm sending the correct value.

I know that client-only captchas are inherently unsafe, but this is a low-consequences app and I need to put something in there.